# How to obtain the probability distribution of a sum of dependent discrete random variables more efficiently

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes, probability-distributions, limit-theorems, binomial-distribution

I hope you are well. Here is my problem.
Let $\{s_0,\,s_1,\ldots,\,s_T\}$ be a sequence of discrete random variables and denote $S_t=s_0+s_1+\cdots+s_t$, with $S_0=0$ and $S_T\leq M$, where $M$ and $T$ are large positive integers.
For all $t\in\{1,\ldots,\,T\}$, suppose that

$s_t|\{S_{t-1}=u_{t-1}\}\sim\text{Binomial}(M-u_{t-1},\,p_t)$, with
$\text{logit}(p_t)=\beta_0+\beta_1\cdot u_{t-1}$,

and $\beta_0\in\mathbb{R}$ and $\beta_1\in\mathbb{R}$ are known and fixed.
I would like to compute $\mathbb{P}(S_{T}=m)$, where $m$ is a large positive integer with $m\leq M$.

Conditionally on $M$, $\beta_0$, and $\beta_1$, one can obtain the probability distribution of $S_T$ recursively. However, I realized that this method is inefficient.

**Question:** How can one compute $\mathbb{P}(S_{T}=m)$ more efficiently? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would state this as:  define a sequence of random variables by $s_t \sim$ Binomial$(M - S_{t-1}, p_t)$, where $$S_t = \sum_{i=0}^t s_i, \text{ and } p_t = \left(1+e^{\beta_0+\beta_1 S_{t-1}}\right)^{-1}.$$  Other than calculating the distribution of each $S_t$ recursively, is there a good way to calculate the probability distribution of $S_t$ for large arguments and large $t$?

Comment: Thanks, Matt F. I took your suggestion into account. I made the question shorter and easier to understand.

Comment: I solved it. I used dynamic programming. Thanks everyone who read the question.